# Update table column for removing unwanted double quotes in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to update table entries simultaneously for all columns in one go.

Suppose in the table, there is one column `EmployeeName` with entries like "SAM", "Jhon" and so on...

I need all this entries under its column should appear like `SAM`, `Jhon` only... Double quotes should not be there, please provide me query for the scenario.

Thanks in advance

Comment: please consider adding sample table data and the expected result in formatted text. 
Also show us your current query attempt

Comment: Very hard to read. Please consider http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and make your question more attractive to read.

Answer (score 4):

Use `Replace` Function as next:-

```
update TableName
set columnName= REPLACE(columnName,'"','')
```

**Demo**:-

```
Create table #Dummy (col varchar(100))

insert into #Dummy values ('"SAM", "Jhon", "Smith"')

update #Dummy
set col = REPLACE(col,'"','')


select *  from #Dummy
```

**Result:-**

```
SAM, Jhon, Smith
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update table1 set column1 = case 
   when column1 = 'entity1' then 'entity2'
   when column1 like '%entity3%' then 'entity4'
   else 'entity5'
end
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.  In particular, it's hard to see how this strips the `"` characters as requested.

Answer (score 0):

To remove left-most quote:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET EmployeeName = SUBSTRING(EmployeeName, 2, LEN(EmployeeName))
WHERE LEFT(EmployeeName, 1) = '"'
```

To remove right-most quote:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET EmployeeName = SUBSTRING(EmployeeName, 1, LEN(EmployeeName)-1)
WHERE RIGHT(EmployeeName, 1) = '"'
```

Or else you can also use a simpler way to remove all the quotes at once.

```
update MyTable set EmployeeName = replace(EmployeeName,'"','')
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not try the `Replace` function.

Syntax: `REPLACE ( string_expression , string_pattern , string_replacement )`

If your table consist the data with double quote in the column, you need to update the table with the following query;

```
Update <tablename>
Set <columnName> = REPLACE(<columnName>,'"','')
where <ColumnWithUniqueVale> = <something>
```

e.g `Replace(EmployeeName,'"','')`

Comment: I do not think, that you want to replace the `"` with a `' '` (blank), but rather with an empty string `''`;

Comment: @shnugo Updated the answer, my mistake. Thanks